# Are there any chew toys that are ACTUALLY tough?

Tags: dogs, chewing

I have two rescue dogs.

Sherman is a 3.5 year old, 110 lb German Shepherd/Boxer/Mastiff (we think) mix that I've had for 3 years.

Chance is a 4 month old, 35 lb Beagle/Hound (we think) mix that we just adopted a month ago.

They chew through every toy I've gotten them in very short order.  Sherman was not really a problem anymore because he had outgrown the "chewing on everything" stage and if a toy wasn't around, he would just not chew on anything.  Chance, however, is still chewing on anything he gets his hands on: shoes, power cords (the reclining seats on my 8 month old couch no longer work because he chewed through the cord), my Cubs World Series hat, the blinds on my windows, crocheted pillow my daughter made me for my birthday, etc.

To help prevent this, I've tried to keep chew toys of different textures around.  This works great, except between the two of them, they basically destroy them almost as fast as I can buy them.  "Indestructible" toys are demolished in a day or two.

Can anybody suggest some toys that are actually durable?

Comment: A large Kong should be able to survive the chewing. We had one with several Mastiffs in the house and it is still in one piece though you can see that it has been chewed on. They aren't inexpensive but they last. Put some peanut butter in them and watch the "kids" have fun trying to get it out.

Comment: I've got one of those, but was hoping for some other suggestions of things with different textures.  They are only interested in the Kong if it has peanut butter or other treats in it.  Don't want to have to constantly be putting treats in it

Comment: Reportedly, black Kongs are the ones given to K9s and are therefore more durable. Other than that, start with the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

This is my opinion and personal choice only.

I've never liked chewed toys, I figure that whatever the toy is made of is likely to be ingested by the dog. I've always preferred bones.

In the answer to [What can I give my dog to chew that will last more than a few minutes?,](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/27861/6796) I detail what I use when a dog is able to chew through smaller raw bones too quickly.

> Raw beef soup bones and long bones.

Brisket bones and raw chicken drumsticks and wings help with chewing, and make an addition to a healthy diet, as an adjunct to the longer lasting bones.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a couple heavy chewers and we give them Elk antlers. You can find small ones at big box pet stores, but if you look online there are several places that will sell you massive ones for much better prices (I'd recommend a shop but don't think that's allowed). Even with very heavy chewers they can last a month or more, and because of the marrow inside the antler, they keep coming back. Best of all, they're odorless and won't stain your carpet.

Only downside is they can be very loud depending on your dogs tactic for chewing them.